# Pass Obj list ajax call to controller mvc 4 , it show null always

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am unable to pass Obj list from ajax call to controller ,it shows null always
i dont know what wrong m doing ?

here's my code
AJAX CALL..

```js
var SkillItems= new Object();
var length = $('#tbl-skill .row-val').length;
for (var i = length; i <= length ; i++) 
{
    SkillItems[i] = ({ Skill_ID: count, Title: title, Skill_Description: desc });
    count++;
}
```

```js
$("#save-unit").click(function () {
    SkillItems = JSON.stringify({ 'SkillItems': SkillItems });
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateBlockUnit", "LPN_BlockPlan")',
        data: SkillItems,
        success: function () {
            // $('#result').html('"PassThings()" successfully called.');
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            // $('#result').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Controller..

```cs
[HttpPost]
public void CreateBlockUnit(List<LPN_Skills> SkillItems) // this SkillItems show null always
{
    // code
}
```

Model....

```
public class LPN_Skills
{
    public int Skill_ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Skill_Description { get; set; }
}
```

Please help me out m stuck

Comment: it is object which i m binding like this  var SkillItems= new Object();   var length = $('#tbl-skill .row-val').length;
            for (var i = length; i <= length ; i++) {
                LPN_Skills[i] = ({ Skill_ID: count, Title: title, Skill_Description: desc });
                count++;
                table.append('<tr class=row-val><td>' + count + '</td> <td> ' + LPN_Skills[i].Title + '</td> </tr>');
            }

Comment: Take a moment to read [Model Binding to a List - Phil Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

Answer (score 1):

SkillItems is one kind of class and you are trying to replace its value with a string class. I'm surprised your not getting an error.

In the `$.ajax` statement try to do:

```
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateBlockUnit", "LPN_BlockPlan")',
        data: JSON.stringify( SkillItems ),
        success: function () {
```

EDIT: I have changed the data portion to reflect correct answer given by Stephen Muecke.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method accepts `List<LPN_Skills>` so you need to create an array of objects and post it

```
var SkillItems = [];
SkillItems.push({ Skill_ID: count, Title: title, Skill_Description: desc });
```

and change the ajax method to

```
$("#save-unit").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateBlockUnit", "LPN_BlockPlan")',
        data: JSON.stringify(SkillItems),
        success: function () {
        },
        failure: function (response) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove this line:

```
SkillItems= JSON.Stringify({'SkillItems' :SkillItems});
```

Try with directly `,`

```
data: {SkillItems :SkillItems},
```